# How to create a chart for a hierarchical database?

Tags: android, database, charts, hierarchy, pie-chart

I want to create a hierarchical chart of a hierarchical database, and I have not found any way to create it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create graphical chart like bar chart, line chart, pie chart etc. Then use aChartEngine library click [here](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/), there are so many other libraries but I used this personally and its very good and easy to implement.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I want to create like this:  http://www.secondprism.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Multidimensional-piechart.png

Comment: Sorry bro I have no knowledge of that. :(